# Call JavaScript function within document.write()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call `openswf` function when i click on `SWF part1` links which is in document.write(), but my problem is when i clicked on `SWF part1` links it nothing happen.

This is my code.

```
<html>
    <a href="#" onclick="Popup();">show popup</a>

<script>
    function openswf(){
        console.log("Do something")

    }
    function Popup()
    {
        var win = window.open('', '',"toolbar=no, width=1000, height=800");
        var doc = win.document.open();
        doc.write('<a href="javascript:openswf();">SWF part1</a>');
        doc.close();
    }

</script>
</html>
```

First i click on `show popup` links to call `Popup()` function and open new popup window which is work properly and then i want to click on `SWF part1` links in that popup but it not working.

Comment: What is `path`, where does it get a value?

Comment: @trincot This is just a demo code, for now i just want to click on links and call openswf() function.

Comment: OK, but it is better to remove `path` then from your question. As it is, it will produce an error. Better make sure your code is fine, except for the issue you address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openswf` is not defined in the popup window, but in the main window. But you can reference the main window with `opener`. I suppose you want to close the popup window when the user clicks:

```
doc.write('<a href="javascript:opener.openswf();close();">SWF part1</a>');
```

Comment: may i ask more question how can i pass variable with openswf() because i try with this code ```doc.write('<a href="javascript:opener.openswf('+path+');">SWF part1</a><br>');``` but it error like this ```missing ) after argument list```

Comment: i got the answer now, i try with this code ```doc.write('<a href="javascript:opener.openswf(\''+path+'\');">SWF part1</a><br>');``` thank you  for help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably calling the default `<a>` onClick event. 
You have to `preventDefault()`.

```js
function Popup(event) 
{
   event.preventDefault();
   var win = window.open('', '',"toolbar=no, width=1000, height=800");
   var doc = win.document.open();
   doc.write('<a href="javascript:openswf(path);">SWF part1</a>');
   doc.close();

}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thank you for response, i'm try with that but it still not working, it error like this "ReferenceError: openswf is not defined"

Answer (score -2):

For starters, the variable "path" is not being passed to your new window. Use this instead...

```
function Popup(path)
{
    var win = window.open('', '',"toolbar=no, width=1000, height=800");
    var doc = win.document.open();
    doc.write('<a href="javascript:openswf('+path+');">SWF part1</a>');
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: That is not going to work, even if `path` is defined.

Comment: @user4723924 i'm sorry, actually this is just a demo code, but what i want is click on links and do the openswf(), now i have edit my code in the question and i have got the answer, thank you for response :)